# How to shutdown pgAdmin 4 from the command line on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, postgresql, pgadmin, enterprisedb

I already know how to do it in the GUI: you find the elephant icon in the Notification area, right-click it, and click "Shut down server". However, I have been unable to find any way to do the same from the command line.

The reason I need to do this is that, when trying to automate the updating of PostgreSQL on Windows (EnterpriseDB installer; minor updates), it appears to fail silently because the GUI normally says that pgAdmin is running and has to be shut down before you can apply the update (not sure why, but it detects it and gives the error if pgAdmin is running).

Answer (score 3):

Kill the process directly through command prompt:

```
taskkill /im "pgAdmin4.exe" /F
```